# Greenplum 5.11 gpload hangs when invoked on master node

Tags: greenplum

```
[gpadmin@mdw ssb_gp_scripts]$ cat d_gpload.yaml
—
VERSION: 1.0.0.1
DATABASE: ssb
USER: gpadmin
HOST: mdw
PORT: 5432
GPLOAD:
INPUT:
– SOURCE:
LOCAL_HOSTNAME:
– mdw
PORT: 8080
FILE:
– /ssb/ssb/dimdate.tbl
SSL: false
– FORMAT: csv
– DELIMITER: ‘|’
– HEADER: false
– ENCODING: UNICODE
– ERROR_LIMIT: 100
– LOG_ERRORS: true
EXTERNAL:
– SCHEMA: orders
OUTPUT:
– TABLE: orders.dimdate
– MODE: insert
PRELOAD:
– TRUNCATE: true
– REUSE_TABLES: true
```

Above is the yaml file on master host.

[gpadmin@mdw ssb_gp_scripts]$ gpload -f d_gpload.yaml -l d_gpload.log .

2018-10-13 13:12:02|INFO|gpload session started 2018-10-13 13:12:02
2018-10-13 13:12:02|INFO|started gpfdist -p 8080 -P 8081 -f “/ssb/ssb/dimdate.tbl” -t 30
2018-10-13 13:12:02|INFO|reusing external table ext_gpload_reusable_179f5634_ced8_11e8_822a_0a78550cb23a

It hangs at this point and never moves.

My cluster is in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to HTTP port 8080 not being open between the nodes.
Opened up this port in AWS Security Group and the issue was resolved.